# What is the Lalitha Sahasranaamam?

Tags: worship, durga, goddess, devi

What is *Lalitha Sahasranaamam*? Why is it important?

During what times of day can one recite it? What are the important verses in it?

What is the history of it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Lalitha Sahasra Namam is from Brahmanda purana (Old epic of the universe), it is divided into three parts.

The first one is called ‘*Poorva Bhaga*’ the middle portion which is called ‘*Stotra*’ which consists of 1000 Namas (names) and the last portion is called ‘*Uttara Bhaga*’.

The Poorva Bhaga talks about its origin. The Uttara Bhaga gives details of the benefits of recitation of this Lalitha Sahasranamam.

Since there is a specific question about the recitation of this Sahasranamam, its benefits include disease free life, no pre-mature death, begetting children, etc. Normally such benefits are cited for all the stotras. The timing of recitation is clearly spelt out in the uttara bhaga. To begin with the least, it is said that one should recite this at least once in his/her life time

You can read more from the below given links,

- [Reference 1](http://stotraratna.sathyasaibababrotherhood.org/g7.htm)
- [Reference 2](http://www.starsai.com/lalithambigai-goddess-lalithasahasranamam.html)
- [Wiki Reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lalita_Sahasranama)
- [How to start reciting the Sahasranaamam](http://taksu.wordpress.com/2006/12/08/how-to-start-reciting-lalitha-sahasranama/)